# What are some automated test suites for testing IE 6,7,8 compatibility for a website?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I'm looking at several websites that have complex web-clients. They have been developed using Chrome/Safari/Firefox; I would like to test them for compatibility with IE 6/7/8.

Are there any automated tests/tools/test suites that will help with the work? Preferably tools that are specific to this kind of problem - and will stress the kinds of corner cases that are likely to come up in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may be after something like this: **http://triflejs.org/** (currently in beta)

Its an IE port of [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) for running Headless UI tests. It uses the.NET [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class for instantiating a bare-bones IE engine.

IE provides an emulation environment for running earlier versions so you can run as IE7, IE8 and IE9 if you have IE9 installed.

If you combine [TrifleJS](http://triflejs.org) (IE), [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) (Webkit: Chrome + Safari) and [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org) (Firefox) you can run headless tests in all common browser environments using the same test scripts and API.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

It is a website testing tool. It allows you to write tests which can then be run in all the major browsers.

It has an IDE for creating the tests; this is written as a Firefox plug-in, so you need Firefox if you want to use the IDE, but the actual tests themselves can be run in any browser, including all versions of IE.

The IDE produces test scripts which you can also edit in a normal text editor, or even write them from scratch without using the IDE.

Finally, it has integration with various programming languages, so you can write your tests in PHP, C#, Java, and others, which means you can incorporate them into your standard unit test suite.

We're still using Selenium v1, but version 2 is available, which pulls in work from (and effectively merges it with) a competing project called Webdriver. More info on this merging of the two projects can be found here: http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/why-should-i-move-to-selenium-2.html. The resulting system is said to be much better than Selenium v1 -- which was already good, so it should be awesome. However it does require you to rewrite all your tests from v1, which is why we haven't migrated yet.

Selenium is the most well known browser testing tool, but another similar tool is [Watir](http://watir.com/), this is more heavily linked specifically to the Ruby language than Selenium, which is language-neutral, but it can nevertheless be used to test any site.

Hope that helps.